# Put a wrapper div around every second row in drupal view

Tags: views

Hi there I am trying to use a views template override to put a wrapper div around every group of two rows. If the last group only has 1 row ( say if there were 5 rows total ) I want to end the wrapper div.

I found some code for this but it's not working I am getting zero output from this I can see my comment tag but that it.

```
<!-- test row output -->

<?php 
$group_nr = 1;                  // first group number
$last_row = count($rows) -1;    // last row
$wrapper  = 2;                  // put a wrapper around every 2 rows
?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php if ($id % $wrapper == 0) {print '<div class="row">'; $i = 0; $group_nr++; } ?>
<?php print $row; ?>
<?php $i++; if ($i == $wrapper || $id == $last_row) print '</div>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong

My template is called views-view--homepage-awards--block-2.tpl.php

I want my output to look like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div>row1</div>
  <div>row2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>row3</div>
  <div>row4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div>row5</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not saying this is not possible, but I am curious, what is your end goal? What are you trying to accomplish by wrapping the rows this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should accomplish it:

```
<?php
  $last=count($rows) - 1;
?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <?php if (!($id & 1)): // if this an even row id, open the <div> ?>
    <div class="row">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($id==$last || ($id & 1)): // if this the last or an odd row id, close the <div> ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It'll wrap each group of two rows with a `div` with a class of `row` and make sure if it's an odd number that the final `div` is closed.

Now, if you want to remove all the classes from those inner rows that Views inserts, then you just need to clean them up or out of that obvious `if` in the middle.

CAVEAT:  If you have done anything with Views pre_render()ing or other similar hooks that have deleted any of the rows out of the results and not reset the ids to be consecutive, this logic will most probably fail.